# How to create a numbered list in Elementor?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

There's no option in Elementor to create a numbered list, one can only create an icon list. The option seems to exist for the pro version, as a "table of content". Is there a workaround to create a numbered list anyway for non pro users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Text editor element & use HTML

```
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item  2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been already answered in an HTML way but if you do not code HTML and CSS, styling that can be a pain. You can also use `Heading and Text Editor` widgets but you should change their positioning to `Inline` in Advanced tab. Then you can use Heading as numbers and Text Editor for the list content. Lastly, you should play with `margins` of text editor to align vertically and horizontally to Heading (which was configured as numbers before). As you may know to play with margins, you should go to Advanced section in Advanced tab.

Hopefully, this was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Install **Unlimited Elements** for Elementor plugin. After you install and activate it the plugin will show you its widget page. You need to install the only widget called List (inside the Marketing Widgets category) and the widget is free.
The list widget for Elementor have auto-numeration and columns. It suits nicely for describing product features.